# Como alinhar o texto com a imagem quando a imagem tiver um formato vertical

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte CSS:

```
.logos {
    max-width:1024px;
    vertical-align:middle;  
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:auto;
}
.logos img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.logos .box-images div {
  display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  text-align:center;
   width:160px;
   position:absolute;

}

.logos .box-images {
    vertical-align:middle;  
    height: 190px;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    float:left;
    margin:20px;

    /* Centralizando imagens */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.logos .break {
   display:block;
   border-bottom:1px solid #679300;
   clear:both;
   width:auto;
}
```

E a HTML abaixo:

```
<div class="logos">

<div class="box-images">
    <div>Empresa 1</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 2</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 3</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 4</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 5</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="break">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 6</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 7</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 8</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 9</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 10</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="break">
</div>

<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 11</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 12</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 13</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 14</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 15</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="break">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 16</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 17</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 18</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 19</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkte.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box-images">
  <div>Empresa 20</div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoaX.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

Gostaria de alinhar os textos em cima quando a imagem for em pé.

Veja aqui o [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/vrx2c7gu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso?

```
.logos .box-images img{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: isso aí, obrigado. veja como ficou: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/vrx2c7gu/4/

Comment: blz, estamos ai pra isso! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
.logos .box-images img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Adicionei isso no CSS ...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]